# nodemon with ts and vs code attach debugging connection timeout with --inspect

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I try to debug my node application that I wrote in ts. I want to debug with the ts source map of course but somehow it does not work with `--inspect` (connection timeout) and without (no sourcemaps but connects).

My npm command:

```
"dev": "nodemon -r source-map-support/register --watch ./src -e ts --exec \"npm run start\"",
"dev-inspect": "nodemon --inspect -r source-map-support/register ./src/index.ts --watch ./src -e ts --exec \"npm run start\"",
```

My ts settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./build/.tsbuildinfo"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My vs code attach configuration:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "protocol": "inspector", // removed when tried without --inspect
        },
```

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set Node parameters in your Debug Configuration.

like this:-  **--require ts-node/register**
and inside java-script file you have to set server.ts or index.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KUCJ.png)

Comment: Adding the require did not help also I found some settings in vs code launch configuration but they didn't help as well. 
{
            "outFiles": [
                "./build/**"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
        },